# Why is my file being deleted when I change pages?

Tags: android, file, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app, that takes a photo, and saves it to file. Everything seems to work, except for some reason, once I change pages, the file no longer exists.

The following code is written after the photo is taken, and the directory is confirmed to exist

```
writePhotoToFile(dir: string, data: string) {
  this.file.writeFile(dir, 'profile-photo.jpg', data, {replace: true})
  .then(_ => {
    console.log(dir + 'profile-photo.jpg written');
    this.file.checkFile(dir, 'profile-photo.jpg')
    .then(_ => {
      console.log('Confirmed. File was created');
      this.file.readAsText(dir, 'profile-photo.jpg')
      .then(photo_text => {
        //console.log(photo_text);
        this.navCtrl.push(ProfilePage);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Could not read photo file');
      })
    })
    .catch(_ => {
      console.error('Confirmation failed. file was NOT created');
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(dir + 'profile-photo.jpg NOT written');
  })
}
```

From ProfilePage:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    console.log('profile.ts Pre-defined URL: ' + this.user.photoURL);
    if (!this.user.photoURL || this.user.photoURL == this.default_photo_path) {
        this.file.checkFile(this.file.dataDirectory + 'images', 'profile-photo.jpg')
        .then(_ => {
            this.user.photoURL = this.file.dataDirectory + 'images/profile-photo.jpg';
            console.log(this.file.dataDirectory + 'images/profile-photo.jpg exists')
            console.log(this.user.photoURL);
        })
        .catch(_ => {
            this.user.photoURL = this.default_photo_path;
            console.log(this.file.dataDirectory + 'images/profile-photo.jpg does NOT exist');
            console.log(this.user.photoURL);
        })
    }
}
```

The following is the resulting log

```
[02:09:35]  console.log: ionViewDidLoad ProfilePage
[02:09:35]  console.log: profile.ts Pre-defined URL: undefined
[02:09:35]  console.log: file:///data/user/0/com.awedsoftware.calledout/files/images/profile-photo.jpg does NOT exist
[02:09:35]  console.log: assets/imgs/default-user.png
[02:09:36]  console.log: ionViewDidLoad CameraPage
[02:09:36]  console.log: Camera started
[02:09:38]  console.log: Picture success
[02:09:38]  console.log: file:///data/user/0/com.awedsoftware.calledout/files/
[02:09:38]  console.log: file:///data/user/0/com.awedsoftware.calledout/files/images/ exists
[02:09:38]  console.log: file:///data/user/0/com.awedsoftware.calledout/files/images/profile-photo.jpg written
[02:09:38]  console.log: Confirmed. File was created
[02:09:38]  console.log: ionViewDidLoad ProfilePage
[02:09:38]  console.log: profile.ts Pre-defined URL: assets/imgs/default-user.png
[02:09:38]  console.log: file:///data/user/0/com.awedsoftware.calledout/files/images/profile-photo.jpg does NOT exist
[02:09:38]  console.log: assets/imgs/default-user.png
```

Notice in the log, the file was created. I confirmed that the file was created, and read it's contents. To keep things clean, I commented out the code the printed the contents, but rest assured it did do the right thing. The app then pushes to the ProfilePage, where upon ionViewWillEnter(), the file is checked for existence once more, and it no longer exists. Where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `this.file.readAsText(dir, 'profile-photo.jpg')`. As a test do not read the file first.

Comment: This was actually one of the final tests I implemented. Removing the read, results in the same problem.

Comment: `(this.file.dataDirectory + 'images', 'profile-photo.jpg')` Why two different notations? `this.file.dataDirectory + 'images/profile-photo.jpg'`.